# Kineticjs remove multiple shapes

Tags: kineticjs

I've added 10 rectangles that are draggable and I want to be able to remove them when they are clicked on one by one. Right now it is only removing the first one and then it won't remove any more. Is there away to add a click event to the rectangle id?

http://jsfiddle.net/dmYbA/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 400
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {

  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 239 + (i *3),
    y: 75 + (i * 3),
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true,
      id: i
  });

rect.on('click', function() {
   rect.hide();

});

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(rect);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to delete each rect one at a time I first moved the new layer inside of the for loop. I also added a group that each rect was added to. Then inside of rect.on set it to this.remove() instead of rect.remove().

http://jsfiddle.net/DP53S/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 400
  });



for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
   var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    draggable: true
});
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 239 + (i *3),
    y: 75 + (i * 3),
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });

rect.on('click', function() {
   this.remove();
   layer.draw();

});

  // add the shape to the layer
  group.add(rect)
  layer.add(group);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the real culprit would be using this.remove() rather than rect.remove(), good work